# Convert Delphi Set command to C++Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I am converting the Delphi expression seen below to C++Builder. My C++Builder code generates the error message E2299. I put the full text for this error description below. Can you recommend a change to my C++ code to get this working.

```
//Delphi
TYPE
Regions   = (North,South,East,West);
RegionSet = SET OF Regions;
```

```cpp
//C++Builder
enum Regions { North, South, East, West };
typedef Set<Regions, North, West> RegionSet;
```

> E2299 Cannot generate template specialization from 'Set'
>
> You need to add a property to your program.
>
> The declaration of a property specifies a name and a type, and includes at least one access specifier. The syntax of a property declaration is:
>
> property propertyName[indexes]: type index integerConstant specifiers;
>
> where:
>
> propertyName is any valid identifier
>
> [indexes] is optional and is a sequence of parameter declarations separated by semicolons
>
> Each parameter declaration has the form identifier1, ..., identifiern: type
>
> type must be a predefined or previously declared type identifier. That is, property declarations like property Num: 0..9 ... are invalid.
>
> the index integerConstant clause is optional.
>
> specifiers is a sequence of read, write, stored, default (or nodefault), and implements specifiers.
>
> Every property declaration must have at least one read or write specifier.

edit below:

The problem was the typedef seen below would not compile inside a C++Builder function. I had the typedef setup in the CheckRegion function.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::CheckRegion( bool visible ){ 
//C++Builder 
enum Regions { North, South, East, West }; 
typedef Set<Regions, North, West> RegionSet; 
}
```

The solution was to move the typedef to the top of the main form just below TForm1 *Form1; like seen below.

```
//--------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
// use "typedef" here
enum RegionsCpp {NorthCpp, SouthCpp, EastCpp, WestCpp };
typedef Set<RegionsCpp, NorthCpp, WestCpp> RegionSetCpp;
//--------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner): TForm(Owner)
{
```

Comment: Can you show an MCVE to provide context.

Comment: I assume you do not have these lines in *one and the same* file, right?

Comment: Looks like a compiler error in that the error text is for Delphi E2299. The text for C++ E2299 is totally different: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/E2299_Cannot_generate_template_specialization_from_'specifier'_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: Here is the test function I am trying to compile. This generates the E2299 error. I have .PAS files in my project. This may be a conflict with some Delphi code. I did not know this error came from the Delphi compiler. 
`void __fastcall TForm1::CheckRegion( bool visible ){


  //C++Builder
  enum Regions { North, South, East, West };
  typedef Set<Regions, North, West> RegionSet;

  RegionSet reg;


  reg = RegionSet();
  if(visible==true){
  //work here
  }else{
  //work here
  }
}`

Comment: I changed the capital S in Set to lower case so it looks like this `typedef set<Regions, North, West> RegionSet;` This generates a different error. E2257 , expected. The compiler gives the error on this typedef line and highlights the two brackets <  >. Does that help?

Comment: I have created a new C++Builder VCL forms project 32bit and added just one FormClick event. There are only two lines of code in the event This gives the same E2299 error described in the original question.  Do I need a special #include file to use typedef Set<>  `void __fastcall TForm1::FormClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  enum Regions { North, South, East, West };
  typedef Set<Regions, North, West> RegionSet;
}`

Comment: Please don't ask the question in comments. Please edit the question to include the new content.

Comment: Instead of doing this manually, let the Delphi compiler do the translation for you. Just add the .pas file with the declaration of the set to your C++Builder project, and re-build it. The IDE will tell the Delphi compiler to generate a .hpp file with all necessary declarations.

The Delphi command line compiler can also be told to do this, by specifying the -JHPNE flags on the command line.

Note that it is the Delphi, and not the C++ compiler that generates this.

Comment: No, do it manually. It is trivially easy to write one line of code to declare a set. And you certainly don't want to make life hard by putting the type declaration in a different file in a foreign language.

Comment: @homebase It's really disappointing that you have not fixed the question with an edit. Please give back to the community by making this question a useful resource for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `typedef Set ...` at the wrong place.

You can use `typedef Set <...` if you using **NOT** a local `enum Regions`

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormClick(TObject *Sender)
{
 enum Regions {North, South, East, West };
 // You can use "enum" here, but not "typedef Set <..."
 typedef Set<Regions, North, West> RegionSet;
 // next typedef is OK
 typedef int NumberOfParts;
}
```

Delphi you can use TYPE here without problems

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
TYPE
 Regions = (North, South, East, West );
 RegionSet = SET OF Regions;
begin
 [...]
end;
```

C++ Builder following will work

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Enum.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
enum Regions {North, South, East, West };
// use "typedef" here
typedef Set<Regions, North, West> RegionSet;
// also works
// typedef System::Set<Regions, North, West> RegionSet;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  [...]
}
```

You can use `typedef Set <...` if you using a global `enum Regions`

```
#include <vcl.h>
[...]
TForm1 *Form1;
enum Regions {North, South, East, West };
[...]
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormClick(TObject *Sender)
{
 typedef Set<Regions, North, West> RegionSet;
}
```

Comment: FWIW this smells like a compiler bug to me. I don't see any reason why the asker's code should not be valid. Why shouldn't a template be specialised inside a function?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I also do not know that . You can use ` typedef Set<Regions` , if `enum Regions {North...` is defined globally. But not together in the function.

Comment: I see no reason for the code in the comments (!!) not to be valid C++.